# Expect to mount after su login

Tags: bash, expect

My requirement is to mount all the directories on a remote server from local machine. The mount can happen only after i login as su user.

Below is my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

set timeout 20

ip="xx.xx.xxx.xxx"

server_username="root"

server_password="yuyuyuyuyuy"

echo "going to mount the directory with root permission"
CMD1="\$@mount -a "
VAR2=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $server_username@$ip $CMD1
match_max 100000
expect \"*?assword:*\"
send -- \"$server_password\r\"
send -- "su"
send -- \"$server_password\r\"
send -- \"\r\"
expect eof
")
echo "===============Done configuration of Server $ip"
```

but this script does not seem to do anything. it does not any state any error. Can you please help me make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect one or both of 1) unexpected effects of the odd quoting methodology and possible escaping mishaps and 2) you have a bunch of `send` commands with no intervening `expect` statements, which might result in everything being sent before there's anything listening...

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script to something like:

```
expect {
        -re "\"*?assword:*\"" {send -- \"$server_password\r\" }
         timeout {}
       }
```

Sending without expecting usually doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Aman. This piece if code works fine. The problem happens only when I try to do SU and then run mount command. Do you have any idea on that?